# Canvas image parsing orientation not in right sequence

Tags: javascript, canvas, exif

i've image uploader which using canvas and trying to get orientation using load-image.all.min.js is fine. but when i choose multiple image orientation parsing function saving data not one by one.

which means if i choose 1 image. it transferring data to 'upload_canvas.php?ori='+ori with correct ori variable.

but when i choose multiple image to upload example 3 images (with orientation 1, 1, 8) 
it passing data to server upload_canvas.php?ori=8, upload_canvas.php?ori=8, upload_canvas.php?ori=8. only last ori variable.

maybe orientation parsing function already looped before uploading image data to server one by one.

how to transfer image with correct orientation to server?

below my using code.

`document.querySelector('form input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    // Read files
    var files = event.target.files;
    var ori = 1;`

```
// Iterate through files
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

    // Ensure it's an image
    if (files[i].type.match(/image.*/)) {

    //Get image orienatation
    loadImage.parseMetaData(files[i], function (data) {         
        if (data.exif) {
            ori = data.exif.get('Orientation');
            console.log("ori: "+ori);       
            } else {ori = 1;}
        });

        // Load image
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {

            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function (imageEvent) {
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                drawImageIOSFix(canvas.getContext('2d'),image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, width, height);

                // Upload image
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                if (xhr.upload) {

                    // Update progress
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event) {
                        var percent = parseInt(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                        progressElement.style.width = percent+'%';
                    }, false);

                    // File uploaded / failed
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                               //some code
                            } else {
                                imageElement.parentNode.removeChild(imageElement);
                            }
                        }
                    }

            xhr.open('post', 'upload_canvas.php?t=' + Math.random()+'&ori='+ori, true);
            xhr.send(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));

                }

            }

            image.src = readerEvent.target.result;

        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }

}
// Clear files
event.target.value = '';});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `ori` is a global variable, that is shared between all images.  The code in the .onload functions aren't run immediately, but only after your for() loop has gone through all the images.  At this point `ori` will contain the orientation of the last image.

To fix, move the variable and parseMetaData into the reader.onload function.

```
...
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (readerEvent) {

        var ori;

        loadImage.parseMetaData(files[i], ...)

        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function (imageEvent) {
...
```

Warning: Not tested!